# Web Server OAUTH flow without user interaction

Tags: rest-api, authentication

I am trying to access Salesforce resources , through another application using an integration user. There is no user intervention to click/approve/allow the authentication. All needs to happen through program. My ask is- 
Can I use Web Server authentication flow or User-Agent authentication flow?
I want to avoid UserName-password flow.

Comment: @David Reed - Is it possible to use web server to have interaction only once and then use refresh token returned by web server to renew the access token each time ?

Comment: Yes. That could be the Web Server Oauth flow.